# Example how to use catboost with the time series data

Tags: catboost

In the introduction/promo video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8Q_orF4tcI) you have mentioned that Catboost can analyse the time series historical data for weather forecasts.

But I was not able to find anything like this in tutorials: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/tree/master/catboost/tutorials

Comment: An English [version of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8Q_orF4tcI)

Comment: Search for examples and tutorials on how to apply gradient boosting methods to time series and forecasting. These will probably be useful in the case of catboost too.

Comment: You found a good example on this @Alex?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of time series models using CatBoost (no affiliation):

1. [Kaggle: CatBoost - forget about time series](https://www.kaggle.com/code/vlasoff/catboost-forget-about-time-series/notebook)
2. [Forecasting Time Series with Gradient Boosting](https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py39-forecasting-time-series-with-skforecast-xgboost-lightgbm-catboost.html)

One thing I see around that I don't have first-hand knowledge of is using the has_time parameter to specify that the observations should be ordered (and not randomized) using a timestamp column.

Comment: How can I use has_time=True with a timestamp column? There is not any example on the whole Internet.

Comment: best "documentation" I could find about this parameter is here https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1076